# A decomposable ideal is radical if and only if it has no embedded ideals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

[Show that a radical ideal has no embedded prime ideals.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1721542)

The only if direction is easy to deal with and it was also be discussed in the link above. I think the converse is wrong but I cannot think of a counterexample. (Actually I hardly have any concrete examples in commuatative algebra...). Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

An example of a non-radical ideal without embedded primes is every primary ideal that is not prime.